# UNNotificationServiceExtension exit calling CNContactStore enumerateContacts

Tags: swift, xcode, cncontactstore

I'm using the UNNotificationServiceExtension to replace a phone number with a name in a notification. I'm attempting to lookup the phone number in CNContactStore and replace the Ph# with the contact name.

My issue is that when I call CNContactStore **enumerateContacts(with: keysToFetch: )** the extension is exited without ever return from the **enumerateContacts** call.

If on the other hand I call CNContactStore's **unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keys)** it returns as expected. Unfortunately, however, this call will not find a phone number. The only way I've found of looking up a phone number is to call **enumerateContacts**.

I use the same code to lookup phone numbers in my app and it works fine. I can also replace the text in the notification extension w/o issue. The problem only occurs when I try to call **enumerateContacts** inside the Extension.

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    let searchPhoneNumber = "5555551234"

    let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
    let contactsStore = CNContactStore()
    do {
        try contactsStore.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)) {
            (contact, error) -> Void in

            print("We never get here!!!")
            if (!contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty) {

                for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                    if phoneNumber.value.stringValue == searchPhoneNumber {
                        // swap number for name
                        self.bestAttemptContent?.body = contact.givenName
                        contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent!)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("And we never get here.")
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent!)
        return
    }
    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent!)
}
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

From UNNotificationServiceExtension https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

> That method has a limited amount of time to perform its task and execute the provided completion block. If your method does not finish in time, the system calls the serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() method to give you one last chance to submit your changes. If you don't update the notification content before time expires, the system displays the original content.

I guess that looping through contacts exceeds the allocated time for the method to complete.